# how to get the unique primary key in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I have this table and this is my migration for the same

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('voucher_id');
        $table->integer('voucher_item_id');
        $table->integer('voucher_item_quantity');
        $table->integer('voucher_dealer');
        $table->integer('voucher_item_main_category');
        $table->integer('voucher_item_sub_category');
        $table->integer('voucher_type');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
```

and this is the model

```
use softDeletes;
use Notifiable;
protected $primaryKey = 'voucher_id';    
protected $table = 'vouchers';
```

now the voucher_id is the `primary key` .. 
and its can be the same number for multi rows .. 
like this

```
id    voucher_id   item_total  
1     1             15
2     1             16
3     1             17
```

now in the page `vouchers.index` its going to show the three rows id,1 id,2 id,3
how can I let Laravel remove the duplication from the primary key and use only one number from the duplication 
and how can I make `one-to-many` relationship in one table 
like 
`select * from vouchers where voucher_id=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a column unique:

```
$table->integer('voucher_id')->unique();`
```

But if you only need the `voucher_id` as the primary key to that table i would recommend you to remove the `id` column and add the following:

```
$table->integer('voucher_id');
$table->primary('voucher_id');
```

This way you will have `voucher_id` as primary key and it will be an unique value.

You migration will be:

```
$table->integer('voucher_id');
$table->primary('voucher_id');
$table->integer('voucher_item_id');
$table->integer('voucher_item_quantity');
$table->integer('voucher_dealer');
$table->integer('voucher_item_main_category');
$table->integer('voucher_item_sub_category');
$table->integer('voucher_type');
$table->timestamps();
$table->softDeletes();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your migration like this:

```
    $table->integer('voucher_id');
    $table->primary('voucher_id');
    $table->integer('voucher_item_id');
    $table->integer('voucher_item_quantity');
    $table->integer('voucher_dealer');
    $table->integer('voucher_item_main_category');
    $table->integer('voucher_item_sub_category');
    $table->integer('voucher_type');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
```